# Extracting the top three to five values for multiple tables

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

Consider the following code that identifies the table and columns where a table name matches a given naming convention:

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE t.name LIKE '%TABLE%'
ORDER BY table_name
```

Results of this code would look something like this:

```
TableNm | ColNm
Table 1 | Column 1
Table 1 | Column 2
Table 1 | Column 3
Table 2 | Column 1
Table 2 | Column 2
Table 2 | Column 3
Table 2 | Column 4
Table 3 | Column 1
Table 3 | Column 2
```

I would like to modify this code by also providing the top three to five values (in the SELECT TOP # sense, not necessarily the most used values) in each column so we have an idea of what data is stored in each column for multiple tables.  For example:

```
TableNm | ColNm    | TopVal1     | TopVal2     | TopVal3
Table 1 | Column 1 | Top Value 1 | Top Value 2 | Top Value 3
Table 1 | Column 2 | Top Value 1 | Top Value 2 | Top Value 3
Table 1 | Column 3 | Top Value 1 | Top Value 2 | Top Value 3
Table 2 | Column 1 | Top Value 1 | Top Value 2 | Top Value 3
Table 2 | Column 2 | Top Value 1 | Top Value 2 | Top Value 3
Table 2 | Column 3 | Top Value 1 | Top Value 2 | Top Value 3
Table 2 | Column 4 | Top Value 1 | Top Value 2 | Top Value 3
Table 3 | Column 1 | Top Value 1 | Top Value 2 | Top Value 3
Table 3 | Column 2 | Top Value 1 | Top Value 2 | Top Value 3
```

Comment: I think you should consider a row-by-row (cursor) solution. And also dynamic SQL.